Send part of Postman request as XML / HTML format
I have API which consumes JSON format, but internally it does have filtering over Stream API
.filter(input -> input instanceof Element)

Per documentation Element -
The <code>Element</code> interface represents an element in an HTML or XML document

I dont know how to create POST request for this purpose
I need to create POST request in Postman which will be in JSON format, but internal element in XML / HTML format for body
This Body
{
  "doXmlCleanRequest": {
    "mapping": "cdi-legalParty-clean",
    "data": {
      "any": [
        "<root><item>1</item></root>",
        "<root><item></item></root>",
        "<root><item>2</item></root>",
        "<root><item>2</item></root>",
        "<root><item>true</item></root>"
      ]
    }
  }
}

returns - 200 ok with empty data back as per filtering above
{
    "doXmlCleanResponse": {
        "data": {}
    }
}


First of all WHY? Also how do you parsing that?

to be honest, the endpoint itself was written not by me. So, I can't tell why unfortunately

Can you answer second question? First one was rhetorical anyway.
